# Do I have to write my book in the main character's POV?

Tags: characters

I know there's 3rd person etc... but can a story be told from a secondary character's POV? or does that never happen and would be useless?
I want the story from the girl's view, but i really want the story to revolve around the guy.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the narrator can be a secondary character.

The beautiful [*Song of Achilles*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0062060627)  by Madeline Miller is about the warrior Achilles and his life, but told by his lover Patroclus.

[*The Great Gatsby*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0743273567) is told by Nick Carraway, almost a tertiary character in the love story between Gatsby and Daisy.

All the [Sherlock Holmes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553328255) stories are about Holmes, but almost all are narrated by Dr. Watson.

(Although if I might interject... why, why, why are you having a woman as the narrator if the story "revolves around the guy"? Why can't the woman narrate her *own* story? Why isn't her story interesting enough to tell?)

Comment: Why, why, why does Doyle have Watson as a narrator, if the story revolves around Holmes? Why can't Watson narrate his *own* story? Why isn't his story interesting enough to tell? – @LaurenImpsum Why do you automatically view the fact that a man's story is told from the perspective of a woman as oppressing the woman? Maybe your feminist reflexes are a bit too high strung. Can you not imagine that a woman's view on a man's life might impart interesting and relevant information both on his life and personality as well as on her own?

Comment: @what Your questions are legitimate. Why *isn't* Watson's story interesting enough to tell? Why don't we ever find out what happened to him in Afghanistan? And for the record, Firebird may well have an excellent answer for *why* s/he wants to tell a man's story with a female narrator -- but I'm never going to know if I don't ask. I wasn't posing those questions as rhetorical.

Comment: And what if there is no "exellent reason" why Firebird wants to tell the story of a man through the eyes of a woman? The problem with your interjection is its inherent sexism. You have been triggered by the mention of a woman telling the story of a man, but don't complain about all the other narrators who don't tell their own story (which is every third person narrative – where the narrator is so oppressed she isn't even mentioned! –, every story with a framing narrative, and actually every book written not about the author herself).

Comment: Why don't we hear what happened to Watson in Afghanistan? Because that is a literary device!

Comment: @what What caught my attention was the phrasing. "I want the story from the *girl*'s view, but i really want the story to revolve around the *guy*." So "girl" (child) and "guy" (adult) -- that phrasing has sexist connotations. Did Firebird mean it that way? I have no idea. I think the question is worth asking. Maybe Firebird could have said "I want the story from Person A's view, but i really want the story to revolve around Person B," and then I wouldn't have noticed.

Comment: @what Not every version of "A tells B's story" is problematic. Maybe *this* one isn't problematic. I am asking because I want to know: *is* it problematic? *Is* the story set up so the female character is sidelined? Or is she an equal force in a story which happens to focus on someone else who happens to be male? *That* isn't problematic. If the story doesn't yet exist for us to read so we can make our own decisions, the only thing I can do is ask the question.

Comment: When I google "girl and guy" , I get images of two young adults of equal age.

Comment: The reason Watson narrates is because Holmes is so stunningly brilliant that if he were to narrate his own stories he'd come across as a narcissist and readers wouldn't warm to him. It's okay for Watson to talk about the "singular gifts by which [his] friend Mr. Sherlock Holmes was distinguished." But if Holmes were to tell us about his own "singular gifts" we'd probably find him quite sickening. We don't hear Watson's story because it's not the story Doyle wants to tell. And perhaps that's what the OP is doing. Sometimes to avoid an amazing MC coming across as a narcissist you need a Watson.

Comment: Have you read Ready Player One? I spent the first two thirds of that novel wanting to stick my fingers down my throat at the MC going on about how brilliant he was and how he knew every computer game ever devised, ever film ever made and the lyrics to every song. It's a classic example of a brilliant MC coming across as a narcissist and making him extremely difficult to warm to.

Comment: @GGx that's a very interesting perspective — related to *Gatsby.* We can see how much Nick adores him, which helps us as readers to like him, but if he were telling his own story, we might want to punch him for being such a shallow jerk.

Comment: Absolutely. Fitzgerald couldn't have created the enigmatic, rich and handsome Gatsby without Nick. The Nicks and Watsons of the literary world may appear to get overlooked but these brilliant MCs cannot exist and be loved without them.